# accumulate items in mpl sequence

Tags: c++, boost-mpl

Is it possible to write a metafunction to accumulate items in an mpl sequence?

By this, I mean something like:

```
// ops.h
using boost::mpl;
using op_list = vector<>;

using add_op = <<<Method I'm asking about>>>;

...

// some_ops.h
#include "ops.h"
add_op<first_op>;
add_op<second_op>;
...

// more_ops.h
# include "ops.h"
add_op<third_op>;
...

// ops.cc
#include "ops.h"
#include "some_ops.h"
#include "more_ops.h"

// here op_list = vector<first_op, second_op, third_op>;

using Variant = boost::make_variant_over<op_list>::type;
```

I can't seem to figure a way to accumulate types over several includes.

An alternate would be a way to test if a type is defined (something like #ifdef, but for types). That way the sub-lists could be folded in, if defined.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Types are immutable, just like data in a pure functional language. So you won't be able to do able to sequentially modify the type represented by `op_list`.